# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET with SignalR and Azure Web Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, websocket, signalr, azure-web-app-service

I just published my ASP.NET MVC app to an Azure App service. In my app I use SignalR to communicate between my server and clients. In the Chrome DevTools console I get the following error when loading a page:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://MyDomain.com/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=TOKEN&connectionData=DATA&tid=3' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

SignalR then falls back to other connection methods and works fine, but I would like to use WebSockets. WebSockets are also enabled in the App Service settings:

[image: App Service configuration]

**Does anybody know how I can resolve this error and use WebSockets?**

My client side code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var hub = $.connection.frontEndHub;

        hub.client.reportStatus = function (delay) {
            setTimeout(function () { hub.server.reportStatus(); }, delay);
        };

        hub.client.showUsersOnLine = function (users) {
            $('#onlineUerCount').text(users);
        };

        $.connection.hub.start();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Facing the same issue , did you fix this?

Comment: @xSkrappy Not really, please also check out this: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/4132

Comment: Sheesh, been searching for quite some time . I am falling in Long Polling then I will get disconnected and can't reconnect any more >.<

Comment: Hmm, then it seems to be a different problem, as for me only Web sockets don'T work, but all the other channels do...